# How do you change a button text depending on a condition on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, boolean-logic, web-frontend

ReactJS newbie here. I'm trying to learn ReactJS conditional rendering. The plan is to change the button text from "Hide Balance" to "Show Balance" and vice versa upon button clicks. I have managed to change the state of the boolean but the button is not changing its text.
What am I doing wrong?

**Account-Balance.jsx** - This is the child component

```
export default class ViewBalance extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(){
    this.props.setPrivacy(this.props.setPrivacy);
}

render() {
    const buttonText = this.props.setPrivacy ? "Hide Balance" : "Show Balance";
    //true: balance is shown
    //false: balance is hidden

    return (
        <AccountBalDiv>
            <CurrentBal>Current Balance</CurrentBal>
                      //some code
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.handleChange}>{buttonText}</button>
            </div>
        </AccountBalDiv>
    );
    }
}
```

**App.js** - This is the parent component

```
    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

    this.state= {
      balance: 10000,
      setPrivacy: true
    }

    this.setPrivacy = this.setPrivacy.bind(this);
  }

  setPrivacy(){
    
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      setPrivacy: !oldState.setPrivacy
    }));

    console.log(this.state.setPrivacy)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <AppDiv>
        <ViewBalance balance={this.state.balance}
                     setPrivacy={this.setPrivacy}/>
      </AppDiv>
       );
      }
     }

     export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only passed down `setPrivacy` method (which is confusing considering that there is also `state.setPrivacy` variable) but not the result of the change. So i would rename your state variable like this:

```
    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

    this.state= {
      balance: 10000,
      isPrivate: true
    }

    this.setPrivacy = this.setPrivacy.bind(this);
  }

  setPrivacy(){
    
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      isPrivate: !oldState.isPrivate
    }));

    console.log(this.state.setPrivacy)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <AppDiv>
        <ViewBalance balance={this.state.balance}
                     setPrivacy={this.setPrivacy}
                     isPrivate={this.state.isPrivate}
       />
      </AppDiv>
       );
      }
     }

     export default App;
```

And then in your child component access it:

```
export default class ViewBalance extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(){
    this.props.setPrivacy();
}

render() {
    const buttonText = this.props.isPrivate ? "Hide Balance" : "Show Balance";
    //true: balance is shown
    //false: balance is hidden

    return (
        <AccountBalDiv>
            <CurrentBal>Current Balance</CurrentBal>
                      //some code
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.handleChange}>{buttonText}</button>
            </div>
        </AccountBalDiv>
    );
    }
}
```